# Firebase Storage Metadata Not Showing Up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-storage

I am trying to set metadata for my image but Firebase isn't taking in my custom metadata. After uploading the image I should see my metadata under 'Other Metadata'.

Below is how it's showing up for me now:
[image]

My code is as follows, you can see I am adding custom metadata to my file:

```
import { firebaseApp } from "./firebase";
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { React} from "react";

// Initialize Firestore
const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);


/**** PROPERTY LISTINGS ****/

// Upload 1 file to Firebase Storage
export async function uploadFile(file, houseId, houseName) {

    //const storage = getStorage();

    // Create the file metadata
    /** @type {any} */
    const metadata = {
        contentType: file.type,
        cacheControl: 'public,max-age=300',
        customMetadata: {
            houseId: houseId,
            houseName: houseName,
        },
    };

    console.log("metadata: ", metadata);


    // Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
    const storageRef = ref(storage, 'property_images/' + houseId + '/' + file.name, metadata);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

    // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
    uploadTask.on('state_changed',
        (snapshot) => {
            // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
            const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
            switch (snapshot.state) {
                case 'paused':
                    console.log('Upload is paused');
                    break;
                case 'running':
                    console.log('Upload is running');
                    break;
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            // A full list of error codes is available at
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
            switch (error.code) {
                case 'storage/unauthorized':
                    // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                    break;
                case 'storage/canceled':
                    // User canceled the upload
                    break;

                // ...

                case 'storage/unknown':
                    // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
                    break;
            }
        },
        () => {
            // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
            getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
                console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
            });
        }
    );
}
```

I am even checking the metadata on my console and it's coming out at follows, so I know there are values being passed in:
[image]

Below are my firestore storage rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {

//this is the part we changed...
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
const storageRef = ref(storage, 'property_images/' + houseId + '/' + file.name, metadata);
```

You're passing the metadata to the [`ref` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#ref), which is not an expected argument for that function.

You'll instead want to pass the metadata to the call to [`uploadBytesResumable`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#uploadbytesresumable), which *does* accept a metadata argument

Comment: Awesome! That solved it. I changed the following lines and now I am getting the metadata:     // Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
    const storageRef = ref(storage, 'property_images/' + houseId + '/' + file.name);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metadata);