# Firebase Storage UploadBytes Function Not Accepting Metadata

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase-storage

I am making a website using Firebase that needs to send an image to Firebase Storage and the projects' title as metadata.

In the Firebase Storage documentation, it states that the `uploadBytes()` function can accept: first the ref to the file, then the file itself and finally *the metadata*. (you can find the page i'm talking about [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files))

This is the code that I wrote:

```js
let projectUploadImage = getFiles();
let projectTitle = getProjectTitle();

async function addProject() {

    let metadata = {
        projectTitle
    };
        
    let uploadRef = ref(storage, projectUploadImage[0].name);

    await uploadBytes(uploadRef, projectUploadImage[0], metadata);
}
```

Here I get an error on this line: `await uploadBytes(uploadRef, projectUploadImage[0], metadata);`

The error goes:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(ref: Reference, data: Blob | Uint8Array | ArrayBuffer, metadata?: UploadMetadata | undefined): Promise<UploadResult>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'StorageReference' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reference'.
      Type 'StorageReference' is missing the following properties from type 'Reference': child, delete, getDownloadURL, getMetadata, and 5 more.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(ref: StorageReference, data: Blob | Uint8Array | ArrayBuffer, metadata?: UploadMetadata | undefined): Promise<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ projectTitle: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'UploadMetadata'.ts(2769)
```

I don't know why this happens, somebody please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you can only set specific properties on the top-level of the metadata. If you want to store other values, such as your `projectTitle`, store it under `customMetadata`:

```
let metadata = {
  customMetadata: {
    projectTitle
  }
};
```

Also see my answer here: [Firebase Storage Metadata Not Showing Up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72923963/firebase-storage-metadata-not-showing-up) and the code from this [test bed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/q72923963?file=index.js):

```
const metadata = {
  contentType: "text/plain",
  cacheControl: 'public,max-age=300',
  customMetadata: {
      houseId: "houseId",
      houseName: "houseName",
  },
};
const storageRef = ref(storage, "72923963");
const message = 'This is my message.';
console.log('Starting upload');
uploadString(storageRef, message, "raw", metadata)
```

Comment: This worked, I didn't know you need to place the metadata in the `customMetadata` object. Thank you very much!